# Rail 5 - Testing the mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I am developing a Rails 5 application which involves sending emails.
I have created all emails using the action mailer, and I used rspec and capybara and factorygirl for testing. I need to test if the mails are received correctly to the proper users. I don't know how to test the behaviour of the mailer properly.

Please can someone show me how to test a mailer or where to find a good tutorial to test my mailer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Capybara, I assume you're trying to ensure the emails are sent correctly in your features tests. If so, the capybara-email gem, https://github.com/DockYard/capybara-email, provides a nice way to test emails in your features tests.  Examples of usage are in the README